# I use super() function to call the __init__() of parent class inside that of the subclass,but isn't this supposed to create instance of parent class?

Tags: python

```
class Computer():
    def __init__(self, computer, ram, ssd):
        self.computer = computer
        self.ram = ram
        self.ssd = ssd


class Laptop(Computer):
    def __init__(self, computer, ram, ssd, model):
        super().__init__(computer, ram, ssd)
        self.model = model

      
lenovo = Laptop('lenovo', 2, 512, 'l420')
```

since the `super()` function returns a proxy object , which is an instance of the base class `Computer` in this case, isn't  `super().__init__(computer,ram,ssd)` supposed to create an instance of `Computer` class and not `Laptop` class. Is `self` passed as an argument to `__init__` in this line `super().__init__(computer,ram,ssd)` ?

Comment: `__init__()` doesn't create the instance. The instance is already created when it's called.

Comment: The object returned by `super()` is a proxy for `self`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you read that `__init__()` creates class instances?

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method is an instance method and it is executed after the instance have already been created.

The class method `__new__` is responsible to create a new instance of the specific class, and obviously called before the **init** method of the instance.

By this logic, calling to `super().__init__()` should only initialize parameters of the base class.